# How do I only include visible cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to filter out specific entries in a column.  i.e. Those that are marked complete.

Here is what I have:

```
    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
        For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
        
        If Len(Cells(i, 8)) <= 27 & _
            Cells.RowHeight > 0 _
            Then Cells(i, 8).Clear
        
        Next i
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

It was clearing everything less than 27 characters.
I just added the RowHeight statement and now it doesn't clear anything.
I was looking at using (xlCellTypeVisible) but I'm unsure of the syntax in this situation.

Comment: Replace `... & Cells.RowHeight > 0...` with `... And Cells(i, 8).RowHeight > 0...`

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted version:

```
    last_row = cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Dim rngVis As Range, cel As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next 'for the case of no any visible cell...
     Set rngVis = Range(cells(2, 8), cells(last_row, 8)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If Not rngVis Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel In rngVis.cells
            If Len(cel.Value) <= 28 Then cel.Clear
        Next i
     End If
    
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```